# How to set Cookie name and value with TideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk

How to set Cookie name and value with TideSDK ?

I try from this api:
http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Network.HTTPClient

when I check value from set cookie.Is null. And this code:

```
var httpcli;
httpcli = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
httpcli.setCookie("test","testAA");
alert(httpcli.getCookie("test"));
```

This image after run:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/anRKX.png

Answer (score 0):

I used local storage instead of cookies, and it worked fine.

```
 window.localStorage.test='this is test';
```

And get the value:

```
var item=window.localStorage.test;
alert(item);
```

Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
            var httpcli;
            httpcli = Ti.Network.createHTTPCookie();
            httpcli.setName(cname);
            httpcli.setValue(cvalue);
            alert("COOKIE value: "+httpcli.getValue());
```